# jenkins is not showing ssh server in the build environment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I Have a jenkins setup in aws EC2 instance. I am facing a trouble on creating a job. I am using ssh plugins to do the task in jenkins. Under Build Environment i checked Execute shell script on remote host using ssh. But am not able to select any ssh host. SSH site is showing nothing.

job need to do:need to do a git pull to the server whenever any commit is happened to the repository. 
Repository:AWS code commit
Developer tool using : Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 0):

first you must go to the global configuration page and add a SSH server and from  your job select a configured server and enter the shell commands that should be executetd before and after the build.

if you used a pipeline jenkins with [ssh-agent](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent) :

```
node {
sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
}
```

---

}